# Checking values of two vectors against eachother and then using the column location of equal entries to extract colums from a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm doing a curve fitting problem in Matlab and so far I've set up some orthonormal polynomials along a specified range of x-values with `x = (0:0.0001:40);`

The polynomials themselves are each a manipulation of that x vector and are stored as a row in a matrix. I also have some have data entries in the form of two vectors - one for the data x-coords and one for the actual values. I need a way to use the x-coords of my data points to find the same values in my continuous x-vector and then take the corresponding columns from my polynomial matrix and add them to a new matrix.

EDIT: To be more clear. I have, for example:

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5]
Polynomial =

      1     1     1     1     1     1
      0     1     2     3     4     5
      0     1     4     9     16    25

% Data values:
x-coord = [1 3 4]
values = [5 3 8]
```

I want to check the x-coord values against 'x' to find the corresponding columns and then pull out those columns from the polynomial matrix to get:

```
Polynomial =

          1     1     1
          1     3     4
          1     9     16
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you give a small example with actual values?

Comment: Hi, Luis. Sorry it's unclear. I've edited it to try make it a bit better. I basically just need to check a vector for specific values and then pull out values from another vector which correspond to the same columns.

Comment: It's clearer now. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

If your `x`, `Polynomial`, and `xcoord` are the same length you could use logical indexing  which is elegant; something along the lines of `Polynomial(x==xcoord)`. But since this doesn't seem to be the case, there's a less fancy solution with a for-loop and `find(xcoord(i)==x)`